# A more elegant way to test time passing in mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, enzyme

I recently had to fix a bug with an old react component at work. Generally when fixing a bug, we write a test with it. The problem is, the react component does an asynchronous fetch from the server (I can refactor the code so the async action is moved into redux, but we don't do refactoring as part of bug fixes here) so when testing what the component is supposed to render, I have to wait `500ms` to allow the promise to resolve.

I know I wouldn't have to do a setTimeout if I create an instance of the component and call the method directly, I can just do a `.then`, but we like to test the input/output of the component without calling internal methods.

Is there a more elegant solution than having to set a timeout? here's the current code:

```
it('autofills and locks all the fields where user data is present', function(done) {
    const emailInput = $wrapper.find('#email');
    emailInput.value = 'email@example.com';
    emailInput.simulate('blur');

    // - autofill does an async request
    // - we need to wait for the promise to resolve before
    //   checking if the inputs are disabled or not
    setTimeout(() => {
      const identifierInput = $wrapper.find('#id');
      const lastNameInput = $wrapper.find('#last-name');
      const phoneNumberInput = $wrapper.find('#phone-number');
      const firstNameInput = $wrapper.find('#first-name');

      expect(firstNameInput.html().includes('disabled')).to.be.true;
      expect(lastNameInput.html().includes('disabled')).to.be.true;
      expect(phoneNumberInput.html().includes('disabled')).to.be.true;
      expect(identifierInput.html().includes('disabled')).to.be.true;
      done();
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

" we don't do refactoring as part of bug fixes here"... Wow.

Anyway if you NEED to write a test to complete your job, you will need to mock your API call. That 500ms timeout will fail anytime the network is a bit slow or whatever, it's a very very very fragile test.

Since you didn't specify much about how the request is made I can't tell you anything else, but you will find mocking libraries for all HTTP request flavors: fetch-mock for fetch, nock... There are tons.

The idea is that you should setup a fake answer upfront and return it immediately (with a Promise.resolve() if needed).